# Linear homogeneous DE of minimal order that has the solution $y_1(x) = x^2e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could not solve the following problem. Could you please give me a hand?

Find a linear homogeneous differential equation of minimal order that has the solution $y_1(x) = x^2e^x$

Best,

Alev

edit: Here is my effort

$y_1(x) = x^2e^x$

$y_1'(x) = 2xe^x + x^2e^x$

$y_1''(x) = 2(e^x + xe^x) + 2xe^x + x^2e^x$

$y_1'''(x) = 2(e^x + e^x+ xe^x) + 2(e^x + xe^x) + 2xe^x + x^2e^x$

$y_1''''(x) = 2(e^x+ e^x + e^x+ xe^x) + 2(e^x +e^x  +xe^x) + 2(e^x + xe^x)+x^2e^x+ 2xe^x + x^2e^x$

Comment: Please compute the first 5 or so derivatives and play with their linear combinations to eliminate terms with $x^2$ and then with $x$ and then all the others. And document these your efforts in your question.

Comment: @LutzL I edited my answer, but could not see how to progress: so now if go like $-y_1(x)+y_1'(x)-y_1''(x)+y_1'''(x)-....+y_1^n(x)$ I will get $2((n-1)e^x+xe^x)$ How to continue from here? I guess I am on the wrong way.

Comment: You should clarify if the coefficients of the linear DE have to be constant. From the first two lines you see that $y'-y=2xe^x$ gets rid of the quadratic term, thus reducing the original problem by one degree. Now repeat that reasoning to get rid of the linear coefficient of the exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logarithms, $\log{y_1} = x+2\log{x}$. Differentiating,
$$ \frac{y'_1}{y_1} = 1+\frac{2}{x}. $$
Hence a minimal linear homogeneous DE is
$$ y'_1 -\left(1 - \frac{2}{x} \right) y_1 = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : The derivation of $x^2e^x$ contains the function $x^2e^x$, so with
        $y(x)=x^2e^x $ , you can easily find a relationship between y(x)
        and y'(x).

Answer (score 1):

if it is a linear homogenous, then $e^x, xe^x, x^2 e^x$ are solutions. therefore the characteristic equation is divisible by $(\lambda - 1)^3.$ so the simplest differential equation is $$y''' - 3y'' + 3y' - y= 0. $$

Comment: I have a question: what makes a differential equation simplest? @Chappers ' answer seems simpler, but it has a $x$ term, so can we say it is not simpler?

Comment: i meant constant coefficient ,linear and homogeneous. if you want the order of the differential equation to be sampler than $3,$ then something has to give: linear, hfs, or constant coeff. chappers sacrificed constancy of the coeffs.